# how to kill python from windows command prompt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, batch-file, exit

When my python script is done running code i want to be able to kill the python script from windows command line only and close everything that has to do with python

the python window remains open after all code has been executed even though I have included `exit()` at the end of my code

i have tried

```
taskkill /IM py.exe
```

> ERROR: The process "py.exe" not found.

```
taskkill /IM myScript.exe
```

> ERROR: The process "myScript.exe" not found.

i cannot find any python processes in task manager

can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: it is `python.exe` for 2.x, or `python3.exe` for 3.x, not `py.exe`

Comment: python.exe and python3.exe processes were not found in command prompt

Comment: huh? how exactly you run the script?

Comment: i double click the script from folder

Comment: It can be.... the python already exited, but cmd hanged/stuck.

Comment: try to change Opens with, the actual path where Python is installed on your system

Answer (score 4):

```
taskkill /IM python.exe /F
```

This will force to kill the python.

Answer (score 3):

To *kill* a *task/process* either by using the process id or by the image file name.

`taskkill /IM executablename`

**OR**

*First detects if a process is running, then kills*

`tasklist | find /i "executablename.exe" && taskkill /im "executablename.exe" /F || echo process "executablename.exe" not running`

Answer (score 2):

Just make batch file & run it.

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims= " %%P IN ('tasklist /FO Table /M /NH ^| Find /i "Py"') DO (TASKKILL /PID %%P /F)
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved problem by adding code in python ide :

```
import os
os.system("taskkill /im py.exe")
```

Comment: this is rather hacky solution, but if it works for you, mark your solution as answer?

Comment: I highly suspect the python processes have already terminated, which is why the `taskkill` from CMD did not work, in which case, I don't think it is required to forcefully terminate it with os.system which is basically interfacing with `Windows` to signal taskkill of py.exe

Answer (score 0):

Even this can be tried:

```
@echo off
tasklist /fi "IMAGENAME eq name.exe" && (taskill /Im "name.exe")
```

You can add optional /F flag that means forcefully stopping.

Answer (score 0):

To replace `your script.py` with your script and run this code on cmd.

```
wmic process where "commandline like '%%your script.py%%'" delete
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git-lfs uninstall --local && echo " " > .gitattributes && git add --renormalize . && git commit -m "Restore sanity"
```

is all you need. Credits: https://gist.github.com/everttrollip/198ed9a09bba45d2663ccac99e662201?permalink_comment_id=3695821#gistcomment-3695821